# How to get Quote subtotal by customer Id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, quote, fatal-error

I have used below code to get the quote object from customer id

```
{
protected $_objectManager = null;
protected $_customerSession; 
protected $quoteFactory; 
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
){
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
}

 public function execute(){

  if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
            $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            $quoteData = $this->getQuoteCollection($customerId);
            echo $quoteData->getSubtotal();die;
        }

 }

 public function getQuoteCollection($customerId)
  {
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
    return $quote;
 }
}
```

How to get the subtotal from current logged in customer quote? I am getting fatal error after using above code.Please anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use checkout session `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`

Inject to constructor

```
protected $_checkoutSession; 
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

public function execute()
{
    $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
}
```